# Should I save Canvas Data URL or as Image?

Tags: html, canvas

I have a wizard on my website in which several steps use the HTML canvas tag. The canvas tags allow users to add areas of damage to an image of a car that is set as the canvas base image.

My question relates to how best to save these images. Should I simply save the context data url in my database and populate the canvas each time I view the submitted form or should I dump the canvas data to an image file on my server and then reference this image? I can do either I just wasn't sure if there were any specific pros or cons to them. Any pointers/tips are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the one that has the smaller footprint in the database, as I this is a scalability resource in your application, especially if the database is a purchased resource... even if the database is local I would still go with the smallest data footprint because its a sparse resource when local.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much, I just wanted to double check to be sure.